# How to return instance of MYSQLi connection object from PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There is a problem when using MYSQLi  connection object returned from the following PHP function (PHP version 5.3.10, MYSQL version 5.5.24):

```
function connectDB(){
  $con=new mysqli("host","user","password","database");
  return $con;
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
$mycon=connectDB();
```

The instance of connection object created with this method is not the same comparing to the one created directly without a function:

```
$mycon=new mysqli("host","user","password","database");
```

Output of

```
echo $mycon->host_info;
```

in the first case (with a function) is:

```
Localhost via UNIX socket
```

and in the latter case (without a function):

```
LOCALHOST via TCP/IP
```

Is something wrong with such method of creating a connection?

Comment: For me, both is same, i.e. `Localhost via UNIX socket`

Comment: Nehal, queries executed with the connection returned from the function fail while everything is ok with connection created directly.

Comment: What is a "host" value? Is it local or remote database? If remote do you have local DB with same user and database?

Comment: Host value is "localhost". It's a local database.

Comment: your script is procedural and you use oop interfaces. Im not sure, but i think that `connectDB()` is not returning reference to object but its copy. Than you will have second connection.
Please try to change `connectDB()` and use procedural interface `$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");` And post the differences. More info you find in [manual](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php)

Comment: @WebHQ, thank you for help but that was not the case. I've updated the question with the found mistake.

Comment: And you didn't pass them to function... You can make them global, but passing them to function is much better idea. Best.

Comment: @WebHQ, thank you, the issue is resolved now. I guess I'll have post the answer myself and mark it as resolved.

Comment: feel free to post it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake. The connection was actually made with variables:

```
$con=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);
```

I've omitted variables in the question thinking they were unnecessary details. And it turned out that variables were defined out of the function scope. Connection was created with undefined arguments, I guess with default settings. The thing to note is that there were no warnings.